# Android get nearby comma, space, or period in a string

Tags: java, android, string

I have a `string` and I want to get the first comma, space, or period in it.

```
            int word = title.indexOf(" ", idx);
```

This will get the first space, how Can I make it to get the first thing from space, comma, or period?
I tried using `||` but didn't work.

**ex.**

```
            int word = title.indexOf(" " || "," || ".", idx);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gets the index of the first occurence of space, comma or dot or -1 if none of them could be  found:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[ ,\\.]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(title);
int index = matcher.find() ? matcher.start() : -1;
```

Note that you can pre-compile the pattern and reuse it as often as you like.

See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Note also that if you want to break a text into single words, you can/should use a [`BreakIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/text/BreakIterator.html) instead!

Comment: It is good but the problem that it finds the nearest space etc.. from the start of the string, how do I make it from a specific start(Like from the character 4 of the string)?

Comment: If you want to start at index n, simply call matcher.find(n) instead.

Comment: One more thing, what is the separator? I couldn't get it. IS it the \\?
Like If I wanna add new things how it will be? how to add x ?

Comment: please answer so I accept it. So how do I make it search for space, comma, period, x, #, whatever I want? What is the separator?

Comment: \\ just escapes the dot (.). Usually the dot is the wildcard for 'any character'. If you just wanna have the dot itself, it must be escaped with \\. You can add further characters within the brackets. There is no separator. Every character within the brackets defines a possible match.

Comment: Thanks, do you know what is the breaks(enter) character?

Comment: newline is '\n', so for the pattern use '\\n'.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing isn't valid Java syntax. Use the `indexOf()` method with a space, comma and period, then determine the smallest of these 3 values.

```
int a = title.indexOf(" ", idx);
int b = title.indexof(",", idx);
int c = title.indexOf(".", idx);
```

Then just determine which is the smallest.

A faster way would be to write your own method. Behind the scenes, indexOf will just loop over all the characters. You can do that yourself manually

```
public static int findFirstOccurrence(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == ',' || // period/space) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I get error from this line :         if (s.charAt(i) == ',' || // period/space) {

Comment: You can't just copy paste my code without reading it. I saved time/space by not writing out all of the conditions, instead replacing it with a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you  can't use array of characters for `indexOf`, instead you need to call `indexOf` three times, or you can match a `regex`, the code you provided is invalid java syntax. this symbol `||` is a conditional `OR` operator that you can use to perform boolean operations like

```
if(x || y )
```